# limited-time control in trun-based game [node.js]

Tags: node.js, socket.io, setinterval, time-limiting

I'm creating a card game like Crazy Eights. And I already publish prototype.

Look here http://himapoyo.com

And next, I want to implement limited-time(5 seconds per a turn) If turn-player don't play, I wanna make server skip its player. I write the code and run on browsers but it doesn't work.

```
function Table(tableID, name){
    this.id = tableID;
    this.name = name;
    this.players = [];
    this.deck = [];
    this.aCardOnTable = -1;

    this.turn = 0;
    this.reverse = false;
    this.clearid = 0;
    this.count = 0;
};

Table.prototype.nextPlayer = function(){
    if(this.reverse === false) {
        if(this.turn >= this.players.length - 1) {
            this.turn = 0;
        } else {
            this.turn += 1;
        }
    }
    if(this.reverse === true) {
        if(this.turn <= 0) {
            this.turn = this.players.length - 1;
        } else {
            this.turn -= 1;
        }
    }

    clearInterval(this.clearid);
    var that = this;
    var countup = function(){
        console.log(that.count++);
    }
    that.clearid = setInterval(function(){

        countup();
        if(that.count > 5){　
            clearInterval(that.clearid);
            that.nextPlayer();
            //update_playerlist(table);
        }
    }, 1000);
};
```

error message

```
Missing error handler on `socket`.
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at _hasBinary (/Users/ryu/Desktop/poker/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/has-binary/index.js:48:16)
```

QUESTION: how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Use ES6, this will really help you, and rewrite your code, I mean, write it in a different way, rethink your logic